# Eigen: strange behaviour of tensor multiplication operators

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3, tensor

I would like to use Eigen's tensor class.
I've installed Eigen 3.3.3 and made sure that my project is picking up the right version (not the older ubuntu package)

```
cout<<EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION<<"."<<EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION<<"."<<EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION<<endl;

// prints 3.3.3
```

This code works:

```
Tensor<double, 3> t(3,3,3);
t.setConstant(1);
```

But this code fails:

```
t*=5;
```

The error message complains about the `int` type:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/SandBox/sandbox.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/eigen333/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:103:0,
                 from /home/lars/programming/fsd_cpp/src/SandBox/sandbox.cpp:3:
/opt/eigen333/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h: In instantiation of ‘Derived& Eigen::TensorBase<Derived, AccessLevel>::operator*=(const OtherDerived&) [with OtherDerived = int; Derived = Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>; int AccessLevel = 1]’:
/home/lars/programming/fsd_cpp/src/SandBox/sandbox.cpp:30:6:   required from here
/opt/eigen333/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h:876:36: error: request for member ‘derived’ in ‘other’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
       return derived() = derived() * other.derived();
```

I've tried `t*=5.;` but that only changes the error message to `which is of non-class type ‘const double’`

When I change the code to:

```
t=t*5;
```

The error message becomes rather long: https://pastebin.com/T6kvLaZ9

And the final version:

```
t=t*5.;
```

Surprisingly, this works. I don't understand why the `t*=5.;` produces an error.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned scalar multiplication using the `*` operator is not currently supported by Eigen Tensors. Element-wise tensor multiplication however, is. To scalar multiply a tensor, use the command `t.constant(Scalar)` to create a tensor identical in dimensions to `t` but with all elements equal to the value of `Scalar`, provided `Scalar` is type `float`. Then use the `*` operator to multiply by this Tensor:

```
Tensor<double, 3> t(5,5);
t.setConstant(1);

Tensor<double, 3> ans(5,5) = t*t.constant(5.);
std::cout << t << std::endl;
std::endl;
std::cout << ans << std::endl;
```

produces

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know current Eigen Tensor realization does not support scalar multiplication. 
But you can try convert Tensor to Matrix.

Comment: It's hard to say what is supported and what isn't, the docs are very much work in progress. But I had found this: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support#Using_the_Tensor_module . There is a list "supported features" with the item Coefficient-wise operations (addition, subtraction, ...)

Comment: The conversion of tensor to matrix is not possible, I'm having more than 2 dimensions